# Array decay rule in C vs C++?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, multidimensional-array

why is this legal C but illegal C++ ?

```
int m[4][5];
int *p = m;
```

I think that C is going way to far by decaying m to `int (*)[5]` then to `int *` where seems that C++ does only the first decay only.

Comment: Why do you think it's legal in C?

Comment: Compiler warnings are not just to show some fancy text for movie effects. Enable and pay heed to them!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not legal C. From a clang test just now:

```
example.c:2:6: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'int *' with an
      expression of type 'int [4][5]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

All conversions between pointer types (except `void *`) require an explicit cast in C. If your compiler lets you get away with more, that's on it, not the language standard.

From the spec, **6.5.4 Cast operators**, paragraph 3:

> Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of 6.5.16.1, shall be specified by means of an explicit cast.

6.5.16.1 is the exception for `void *`.

Comment: @HansPassant - no, that's completely up to the implementation. It can provide arbitrary extensions to the language at its leisure.

Comment: ... not many implementations error out if you don't cast your pointers to `void *` when calling `printf` with `%p` specifiers either, for example. That doesn't make it legal C.

Comment: Breaking a "shall" makes the program ill-formed. Now an implementation may (which wouldn't be conforming either) accept it, but it's not ISO C.

Comment: An implementation is allowed to successfully translate an invalid program as long as it produces at least one diagnostic message (§5.1.1.3, and its footnote 8).